# python understanding lists in recursion

Tags: python

I have a recursive function that traverses a tree and gathers a list. I don't understand why I have to convert the "list" to a `list`. I added a comment in the code. removing `list()` would result to an empty list.

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def find_paths(r, sum):

  def helper(root, summ, path, paths):
    if not root:
      return

    path.append(root.val)

    if not root.left and not root.right and summ == root.val:
      """
      if I print path

      [12, 7, 4]
      [12, 1, 10]
      """
      # why is list() necessary here
      paths.append(list(path))

    else:
      helper(root.left, summ - root.val, path, paths)  
      helper(root.right, summ - root.val, path, paths)

    del path[-1]

  paths = []
  helper(r, sum, [], paths)
  return paths

def main():

  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  sum = 23
  print("Tree paths with sum " + str(sum) +
        ": " + str(find_paths(root, sum)))


main()
```

doing it just this way `paths.append(path)` will result to this
`Tree paths with sum 23: [[], []]`

Comment: Please add an example, best if it is an example that fails, that it does not works without the list. Probably it is because list(path) creates a copy of the list.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I added an example

Comment: I just change the list(path) to path[:] just another way of creating a copy and it works, so it is related to copying a list, when you do paths.append(path) you are appending the reference to path, so basically if you modify it in any other call, it becames empty.

Comment: nice so every time it gets passed to the stack it's adding a reference because it's being called from another function. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `list(path)` creates a copy of the list, when you do:

```
paths.append(list(path))
```

You are actually appending a copy of the list, when you do:

```
paths.append(path)
```

You are appending the reference to the list so when you modify it like in:

```
del path[-1]
```

it affects the reference added to `paths`.